# Pointwise convergence of resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $T$ is a quasiniplotent operator and $\lambda_n$ a sequnce converging to $0$. Then clearly $||(\lambda_nI-T)^{-1}||\to\infty$. I am interested for which $x$ we have that  $||(\lambda_nI-T)^{-1}x||\to\infty$. When $T$ is niplotent, it follows from the Neumann series expansion that there exists $x\neq 0$ for which $||(\lambda_nI-T)^{-1}x||$ does not converge to $\infty$. What if $T$ is not nilpotent (in other words $0$ is not an eigenvalue), does it follow that $||(\lambda_nI-T)^{-1}x||\to\infty$ for all $x\neq 0$? If the answer is NO, is it anything known for the set of vectors for which it does?

Comment: Do you mean $\|(\lambda_nI-T)^{-1}x\|\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes. Fixed now.